# JavaScript nested namespaces and state variables

Tags: javascript, nested, namespaces

I am trying to implement nested namespaces using the modules pattern with anonymous functions and closure. I am missing something when it comes to changes in state variables. For example, here is a simple set of nested namespaces:

```js
// namespace 1
var first = (function(){
    'use strict';
    var v = 1;
    function method(){
      console.log("method 1: " + v);
    }
    // namespace 2
    var second = (function(){
      var v = 2;
      function method(){
        console.log("method 2: " + v);
      }
      // namespace 3
      var third = (function(){
        var v = 3;
        function method(){
          console.log("method 3: " + v);
        }
        return {
          v: v,
          method: method
        };
    })();
    
    return {
      third: third,
      v: v,
      method: method
    };
  })();
  
  return {
    second: second,
    v: v,
    method: method
  };
})();

first.method();
first.v = 4;
first.method();
first.second.method();
first.second.third.method();
```

This results in the following output:

```
"method 1: 1"
"method 1: 1"
"method 2: 2"
"method 3: 3"
```

Why doesn't the change to `first.v` stick?

**UPDATE:**
So, I see now why this wasn't working based on feedback. I have now switched over to using object literals. I am still trying to find the best approach to nested namespaces and scoping. Here is my new version of the above code:

```
var first = {
  
  v: 1,
  
  method: function (){
    console.log("method 1: " + this.v);
  },
  
    second: {
    
    v: 2,
    
    method: function (){
      console.log("method 2: " + this.v);
    },
    
    third: {
    
        v: 3,
      
      method: function (){
        console.log("method 3: " + this.v);
      }
    }
  }
}

first.method();
first.v = 4;
first.method();
first.second.method();
first.second.third.method();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
So, looking at different resources, I have updated my approach again. This is the route I tried going down first, but I kept getting a strange error that the functions were not functions. Here is my updated version using the same example:

```
var first = window.first || {};
first.second = first.second || {};
first.second.third = first.second.third || {};

first.v = 1;
first.method = function (data) {
    console.log("method 1: " + this.v);
};

first.second.v = 2;
first.second.method = function (data) {
    console.log("method 2: " + this.v);
}
first.second.third.v = 3;
first.second.third.method = function (data) {
    console.log("method 3: " + this.v);
}
first.method();
first.v = 4;
first.method();
first.second.method();
first.second.third.method();
```

Now I just want to make sure I have the correct scoping. When using `this`, it should refer to the current object's scope and not to global, correct?

Comment: @Scott Marcus, Thanks for the clarification. I see now why that wasn't working at expected. It works great for functions, but not for persisted state. I am switching over to just using object literals. See update.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Nesting functions within functions is not how to create namespaces - - it's how you can create method chaining. To create namespaces, you must create new properties (that are objects) on the object you wish the namespace to emanate from.

Comment: To persist state, you need to be create instances of objects (with the `new` operator), which is a different topic/concept.

Answer (score -1):

Namespaces aren't created by nesting functions. They are created by creating new properties on an existing object and then attaching new members to those properties:

```js
(function(){
  // Just create members of the instance as normal
  // No nesting here. Within a function variables are
  // private, but "this" properties are available
  // and can persist state.
  this.foo = function(){console.log("foo"); };
  this.bar = function(){console.log("bar")};
  this.baz = function(){console.log("baz")}; 
  this.x = 42;
  // We can't change the state of the above variable directly
  // but we can create a function that works with that value
  // and modifies it.
  this.changeX = function(n){
    this.x += n;
  };
  
  // If we create a new property on the Global object 
  // that is an empty object, we'll be essentially 
  // creating a namespace to be accessed from the Global object
  window.namespace = {};
  
  // Then, create new properties on that object, which point
  // to state or behavior that you want to expose in the namespace
  window.namespace.foo = foo;
  window.namespace.bar = bar;
  window.namespace.x = x;
  window.namespace.changeX = changeX;
  
  // And to create nested namespaces, repeat by adding a new empty
  // object as a new property of the current namespace.
  window.namespace.ns2 = {};
  // And then associate internal state or behavior with that namespace
  window.namespace.ns2.baz = baz;
})();

// Since our namespace is attached to the Global object (window),
// we don't have to fully qualify it with window and can just
// access the namespace directly.
namespace.foo();
namespace.bar();
namespace.ns2.baz();
console.log(namespace.x);  // 42
namespace.changeX(-10);
console.log(namespace.x);  // 32
```

Comment: An IIFE is not an instance. In strict mode, `this` will be undefined.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Wording corrected. I know this isn't an instance. I was trying to convey that using `this` (not in strict mode since that was never mentioned) would differentiate between local variables and exposed members.

Comment: Are you trying to encourage using sloppy mode here? `this` in an IIFE does not refer to "exposed members", it refers to members of the global object, which should be absolutely avoided.